# Google App Engine running in localhost environment on Mac

Tags: python, google-app-engine, localhost

I did a bunch of research on this and could not find an answer to my specific problem, although it seems allot of people have been plagued with similar problems.

I am new to Google App Engine and just created an account. I downloaded the SDK for Python 2.7. I deployed the Hello, World! to the supplied appspot.com address and it prints hello world just fine. When I try to run it in my localhost it gives a 500 server error.

I tried creating a few different applications and messing with the port settings, the app.yaml file, and the main.py file. Still cant get it to work.

Im running on an Mac and I did download and install Python 2.7 to ensure I have the latest version. Im also new to Python and App Engine. I come from the world of PHP and XAMPP.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: I would say, definitely you didn't get the configuration correct. did you get the python correctly installed, GAE SDK correctly installed ? can you provide more details as what does the console output when there is 500, etc. etc.

Comment: I did notice that when I run "python" on the terminal it is running version 2.6.1. I downloaded App Engine 2.7. Would that be the culprit?

Comment: yes, you should take that into consideration

Answer (score 0):

You should try Python 2.7.4 which is the version Google links to and run a PHP version compiled with the same modules and option that GAE as well.

Here's a video with the steps
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IFuNNddWQIo